# Troubleshooting Azure DevOps External Repository Cloning Authentication Issue

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYFv1.png)

Good evening,

I've installed Azure DevOps locally on my server, but I'm having trouble cloning my repositories when I'm outside of the network. Even with external access, I receive the following error message:

Cloning into 'C:\Users\matfl\OneDrive\FLD_TECNOLOGIA\DESENVOLVIMENTO\Trust_Novo'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://tfs.azuedev.fldtecnologia.tech/fldtecnologia/Trust_Novo/_git/Trust_Novo/'

I noticed that the option to generate Git credentials is not available in my project.

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Good evening,

I've installed Azure DevOps locally on my server, but I'm having trouble cloning my repositories when I'm outside of the network. Even with external access, I receive the following error message:

Cloning into 'C:\Users\matfl\OneDrive\FLD_TECNOLOGIA\DESENVOLVIMENTO\Trust_Novo'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://tfs.azuedev.fldtecnologia.tech/fldtecnologia/Trust_Novo/_git/Trust_Novo/'

I noticed that the option to generate Git credentials is not available in my project.

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose **machine-A** is the one that your Azure DevOps server hosted, and **machine-B** is another one that you want to clone the repository to.

If both **machine-A** and **machine-B** are connected to Internet, you can try to add the IP address of the **machine-B** into the whitelist of the **machine-A**. Or you also can reference the documentation "[**Web site settings and security for Azure DevOps on-premises**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/websitesettings?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2022)" to try to configure the external access.

If **machine-A** is not connected to Internet, you might need to configure a Proxy Server for external access. More details, you can reference "[**How to install Azure DevOps Proxy Server and set up a remote site**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/install-proxy-setup-remote?view=azure-devops-2022&source=recommendations)".

---